# How to make .bin file from multiple c source code

Tags: compiling

Hi please let me know how to compile [Sony TV source code](http://www.sony.net/Products/Linux/TV/KDL-40CX520.html) using Ubuntu 13.10 for making `.bin` file([system software](http://www.sony.co.in/support/download/579512/product/kdl-22ex420)).

Comment: If I read correctly, you don't need anything to compile. Just copy the stuff to the usb memory.

Comment: No Braiam, i want to know, how to make/build/create that file from source code.

Comment: Err... I read the file and it doesn't have "source code" just a binary. Really, just copy in your usb stick the thing (luckily it doesn't even need Windows) and be done with it.

Comment: @Braiam Source code is at the first link.

Comment: @Shutupsquare err... those are rpm sources, and java, and the linux kernel, and other development headers for stuff. The kdl-22ex420.bin file will not be obtained using them.

Comment: @Braiam Yes and what comes in a source rpm? source code. I haven’t got a clue if he could or could not build the required binary out of that lot though.

Comment: @Shutupsquare common, at least download them and see what they are about... none of them compiled will result in Sony's privative code for their Tv's. You can read the titles going by iptables, libpango, busybox, glib, linux-kernel, etc. all of them are readily available in all Linux distributions and none are able to produce the `.bin` file OP is looking for.

Comment: @Braiam does it surprise you that Sony TV’s run on Linux? Unless you have looked through all the code or documentation then how can you say that he wouldn't get the binary. I make no judgement ever way i was merely pointing out there is source code to compile. I'm not to sure this question has got much todo with ubuntu though.

Comment: @Shutupsquare check Oli answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The source code shown is  not a full distribution.

I suspect you could compile everything *there* by downloading it, extracting and and using `make` (there are readmes too) but the things that hold it all together are missing, likely because they're still stock code (ask Sony - they're still obliged to make any unmodified GPL2+ code available) or they're custom written. I suspect whatever is bootloading this is custom made to some degree.

The process of completing the distribution and actually building it into a bin is not something you can "just do". Sony has the secret sauce. You can ask them about the build environment but I'd start by getting the complete source (for everything open source) and see where you stand.

Failing that, talk to the FSF about Sony being non-compliant. Just understand that there are likely parts that Sony has no obligation to share.

---

I could also be completely wrong. One of these bin files might just be a collection of compiled code (open one up and see - I'd suggest trying to mount one) that just replaces certain components. The base distribution might be completely static.